# How to convert a ConTeXt document to PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: context, conversion, context-mkiv, powerpoint

I created a very simple, ~100-page document in ConTeXt. It only uses `\starttext`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\startitemize`, and `\item`, e.g.:

```
\starttext
    \startitemize
    \chapter{First chapter}
        \section{First section}
            \item This is an item.
            \item This is another item.
            \startitemize
                This is yet another item.
            \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

I set the page layout to screen size and this makes a nice PDF presentation.

I must convert this to PowerPoint format though so others who do not know ConTeXt can edit it. Is there any way to either convert the ConTeXt code or the resulting PDF to PointPoint slides?

Comment: It might seem like a joke but convert pdf to pngs and put them on each page. You'll save lots of time.

Comment: If I just send PNGs, they will not be able to edit the file.

Comment: how are they going to edit if it is not pngs but pdf?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I ask the question. I cannot give the ConTeXt code or the PDF, as both aren't easily edited. I need some way to convert this to a format so that others can edit the resulting file themselves, preferably somehow to PowerPoint, LibreOffice Impress, or a similar file format.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible (and it is unlikely that such a feature will be available anytime in the future).

Comment: @Village If you have the full version of Adobe Acrobat you can [export PDF to PowerPoint](https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/acrobat/how-to/pdf-to-powerpoint-pptx-converter.html) (supports even PPTX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the universal document converter [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html).

First of all you have to export your document as XML/XHTML.  Let's name this file `test.tex`:

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\starttext
\startchapter[title={First chapter}]
  \startsection[title={First section}]
    \startitemize
    \item This is an item.
    \item This is another item.
      \startitemize
      \item This is yet another item.
      \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
  \stopsection
\stopchapter
\stoptext
```

Running ConTeXt on `test.tex` will create a directory `text-export` with the contents

```
├── images
├── styles
│   ├── test-defaults.css
│   ├── test-images.css
│   ├── test-styles.css
│   └── test-templates.css
├── test-div.xhtml
├── test-pub.lua
├── test-raw.xml
└── test-tag.xhtml
```

We can now use pandoc to convert `test-div.xhtml` to Powerpoint using

```bash
pandoc -f html -t pptx -o test.pptx test-export/test-div.xhtml
```

This will probably look like garbage and everything will be completely screwed up.